# Is there a way to add text content at the end of a responsive slideshow photo gallery?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, css, responsive-design, slideshow

I'm developing a website on Wordpress and I'm trying to figure how to add text at the end of a slide show to make the website simpler. This website post has exactly want I want https://hypebeast.com/2017/7/calvin-klein-flagship-makeover

I tried to "view source" the slideshow, but I was unsuccessful. I want the same exact style slide.

Can anyone help?

Comment: another great example https://hypebeast.com/2017/7/supreme-tees-sold-k-mart-4-usd

Comment: another one with out text https://hypebeast.com/2017/7/diamond-supply-co-moving-speed-of-life-exclusive-collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example that you've provided takes an unordered list element `<ul>`, and transforms it into a slideshow. This example uses a plugin called ["FlexSlider"](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html). Here's an implementation of FlexSlider with a "text" page as the last slide that I hacked together:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Place somewhere in the <head> of your document -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<!-- Place in the <head>, after the three links -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/230629/pexels-photo-230629.jpeg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg" />
    </li>

    <li class="slide related-posts-slide hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs flex-active-slide">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p>You can put all of your content here, and treat it as it's own page.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could make this a live example on jsfiddle or other?

Comment: @Moja [Here'a jsfiddle. I couldn't include the plugin files, so I've added them inline](https://jsfiddle.net/2gsm5L9o/)

Comment: https://hypebeast.com/2017/7/diamond-supply-co-moving-speed-of-life-exclusive-collection

Comment: @Moja There are examples that do the same thing [on the FlexSlider website.](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/)